# contact form not submit when click on Submit button

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a WordPress eCommerce website, I have been updating this website after updating website contact form 7 not working, when click on submit button loder only loading not submitting form

Comment: Is there any error shown on the javascript developer console? Else, read about enabling debug log: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
and check the error log for possible PHP errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I do hope you have a child theme, try and modify the contact form 7 setting's details within the dashboard. If that fails try disabling and re enabling /reinstalling the plugin and clear cache to see if that resolves the issue.